# How to block access to an IP via a specific port

Tags: networking, port, iptables

I have obtained a static IP for my machine. From a site (host by my IP), it send a query like http://x.x.x.x:1234.... . I have to change iptable configuration ( supposed) that no one else can send a query to my server.

What will be its solution to stop IP with a specific port ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a router in your network, you can use ACL (Access control list) to accomplish this.

```
STEP 1: Configure a ACL to allow only your PC (permit <your IP> <server IP> precedence 1)
STEP 2: Configure a ACL to deny all other PCc (deny any <server IP> precedence 2)
```